# ReSharper and Ruleset files

Tags: resharper, fxcop, rule-engine

I created a project and added a ruleset file. I then broke the rule on purpose to ensure that it was working, but it wasn't.

Here is the rule I enabled.

> CA2211 - Microsoft.Usage -
>   "Non-Constant fields should not be
>   visible."

**Bad Code:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string foobar = "Hello World";
}
```

It compiles just fine, no warning or error. I think it might have to do with ReSharper overriding it? I'm not sure. Any thoughts as to how to fix this?

Comment: This is probably a question/bug you want to file with JetBrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Compare Visual Studio 2010 Products](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/63ce22f6-21a3-4e4a-92df-7f1b8f866966)...

If you are running VS 2010 Premium or Ultimate you should have "Static Code Analysis" available. If you are and that feature is not showing up, you might look at reinstalling Visual Studio. If you aren't running either of those, you won't have access to that feature, sorry.

However, you can still use [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=917023f6-d5b7-41bb-bbc0-411a7d66cf3c) to validate your code.

---

NOTE: The link is to FxCop 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

CA2211 only verifies static fields.  If you want to check instance fields as well, you should enable [CA1051 (Microsoft.Design.DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182141.aspx).

Comment: Well, I ended up checking EVERY box (all rules) for the ruleset.... it still doesn't give me any warnings when I do bad coding. I think it's just ReSharper took over that job somehow.

Comment: When you say that you "added a ruleset file", did you simply add the file to the project, or did you actually specify it as the ruleset for the project (e.g.: via the Code Analysis page in the project properties dialog)?

Comment: I don't have a "Code Analysis" option in my properties dialog. I think the section got killed because of resharper. I do remember seeing it beforehand. :-/

Comment: We have ReSharper, and we have a "Code Analysis" page in project properties. So unless there's something unusual about your setup, I don't think ReSharper is the problem. Have you tried disabling ReSharper just to see if that makes a difference?